# Java reduce dynamic regex pattern to eliminate duplicated qualifiers

Tags: java, regex, string

Yes I know another regex question, MEH! Well this is kind of regex but more pattern recognition which drives regex generation...

Anyway, I'm working on a brain teaser and need to convert a binary representation of a string of characters to some other string representation. i.e. `0 = A|AA|AAA|AAAA+` and `1 = A|AA|AAA|AAAA+|B|BB|BBB|BBBB+` does `1010101010 == AAAAABBBBAAAA`? Given a rather large input file.

My solution was to create regex on the fly using the pattern `A+` for `0` and `(A+|B+)` for `1`.

The issue is that as I iterate the input which can be pretty large (binary representation is up to 150 chars and the AB notation can be up to 1000 chars), I end up with a large regex pattern that is not performing quick enough for my needs (needs to be able to perform a match on a character string up to 1000 characters in less than 10 seconds)

To speed up the solution I wanted to reduce the size of the generated regex so for the input of a binary representation of `1010101010` I want the regex to be `(A+(A+|B+))+` instead of my generated `A+(A+|B+)A+(A+|B+)A+(A+|B+)A+(A+|B+)A+(A+|B+)`

My thought was that I could detect the repeating pattern and reduce it to just the first sequence that is repeated and then generate the regex string off of that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to make one big pattern that matches the whole file you could go for partial matching using a loop and `matcher.find()` to iterate through the individual matches of `A+B+`.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("A+B+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find())
{
    String part = matcher.group(); // this is the matched part
}
```